# I've heard that Hegel's view on how to attain absolute truth differed from Kant's. In what ways?

Tags: kant, hegel, phenomenology

I think, from memory, Hegel said that the absolute truth can be known through a dialectical process between the object and the thing-in-itself. But, how does that differ from Kant's opinion on the same matter? I don't remember what Kant said about the absolute truth.

Comment: Kant said we cannot know absolute truth. The 'thing-in-itself' would be unknowable. I'd;say Hegel's view is considerably more sophisticated. Kant points us towards mysticism but Hegel more or less pushes us down the rabbit-hole. .  .

Comment: @PeterJ: Well, Kant's Fact of Reason (consciousness of the Moral Law) is what comes closest to what he calls *intellectual intuition*, i.e. direct insight into the real fabric of the noumenal, although he is careful to point out that the FoR is exactly **not** to be understood as theoretical knowledge. In some respects, Kant and Hegel are closer than most authors acknowledge, since both emphasise that it is only in **practice** (i.e. active grappling with nature) that we get a glimpse at the absolute.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - Do either of them claim to have had 'glimpses of the absolute? I feel they are both heading in the same theoretical direction, as you say, and that it's the correct one, but still have a way to go to catch up with the descriptive theories of those who claim it is possible to know the absolute. I admire both, though, for going deeper than most.

Answer (score 1):

Kant regarded the "absolute truth", or the knowledge of the thing in itself, to be impossible - because thought is a *mere* synthesis (as Kant likes to stress) which works with content that is externally provided *via* a sensuous intuition. We cannot know the object as such, as it is determined only by the pure concepts of the understanding, or the categories, but only as object in time - the notion of which according to various categorial determinations are called the *schemata* or, collectively, the *schematism* (cf. *Analytic of Principles*). In other words, there is a form which all of our knowledge has which is the form of our sensibility, contingent and animal-specific, but isn't the form of the thing-in-itself - so it isn't knowable. This is Kant's **formal idealism**.

Hegel, in contrast, thinks that thought gives itself its own content. Indeed, the human understanding is necessarily finite, so, as knowers of the external world, we are constrained in the mannor explained by Kant. But, Hegel says, categories, due to thinking being more than mere combination of content externally given, have their own content and so can be known independently of their application to  time (as schemata).

For both Kant and Hegel absolute knowledge is necessitated by empirical knowledge. Reason, the power which is absolutely unconditioned (in contrast to the Understanding) by the object of  empirical knowledge, however, for Kant can only produce (in its theoretical form) regulative Ideas which guide our empirical research as limit-concepts (like: the notion of an ultimate science where everything is explained by subsumption into causal chains). In fact, they're necessarily involved in the notion of a systematic body of knowledge at all. Hegel here agrees with Kant as far as Kant ascribes *necessity* to the Ideas of Reason. For Kant, however, it is mere *subjective* necessity (it's a complex notion, but Kant says that Reason's necessity is not due to the nature of its object, which is an unknowable thing-in-itself, but due to the nature of the Understanding, so "subjective" here means: non-objective, i.e. not due to the object of Reason's cognition). For Hegel this is a faulty dualism - elaborating his alternative would require too much space, however. In short: experience isn't an external constraint on Reason but a mode in which it functions.